# Issue with Google Apps.Script calendar.getEvents

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that I use to pull events from a Google Calendar into a Google Sheet. I use this script a lot, and generally just copy the exact format of the sheet and the script into a new workbook as needed. It usually works beautifully, and currently all the other integrated uses of this are doing just fine. However, I'm doing it again and I'm getting an error. Below is the code, followed by the error message I've been getting. Any thoughts?

```
function importCalendar(){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Calendar Import'); 
  var calendarName = sheet.getRange('C2').getValue(); 
  var start = sheet.getRange('C3').getValue(); 
  var end = sheet.getRange('C4').getValue(); 
   
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarName); 
  if(calendar) {var calendarId = calendar.getId();} 
  if(!calendar) { 
    var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0]; 
    var calendarId = calendarName; 
  } 
   
  var events = calendar.getEvents(start,end); 
  var eventDetails = []; 
  for(var i = 0; i<events.length; i++){ 
    eventDetails.push([events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation()]); 
  } 
   
  //write calendar details to spreadsheet 
  var startRow = 8; 
  var startCol = 2;  
  for(var j = 0; j<eventDetails.length; j++){ 
    var tempRange = sheet.getRange(startRow+j, startCol, 1, 5); 
    var eventArray = new Array(eventDetails[j]); 
    tempRange.setValues(eventArray); 
  } 
  return eventDetails; 
}
```

The error:

```
2:09:18 PM  Error   
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEvents' of undefined
importCalendar  @ importCalendar.gs:14
```

Comment: Check cell `C2` to see if it contains what you expect.

Comment: ...yup. Donked that one up good. Thank you!

Comment: You can post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer, thanks to Marios, was that the C2 cell did not have the correct data in it (the calendar ID was in a different cell). Fixing that fixed the issue!